# 12 weeks in America - What questions should I prepare for?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, uk-citizens

So, to put it simply I'm going to America for 12 weeks and staying with a friend and her parents the entire time. They've already agreed to feed me and pay for all my basic needs if necessary.

I've brought travel insurance for the time I'm there as well.

SO my question is, what questions and the likes should I prepare for?

I don't have a job since I'm starting college this September. So the whole purpose of this trip is to spend the summer in America since I'll be too busy for any long trips when I'm in college.

I don't plan on lying to the officer, but I do want to be prepared to let them know that this is purely a long vacation since when I'm a student I won't have the funds or time to do something like this till I'm finished.

Funds - Since I'm staying for so long I'm unsure of how much money they'll expect me to have? I'm not paying for housing since I'm staying with my friend and the food I do buy will be restaurant stuff since obviously they'll have food in the house. I plan on having at least $200 upon entering the USA, but will be receiving more money from my parents at home as time goes on?

I feel like I'm forgetting something but I'm just nervous I guess? I stayed in the USA with the same family for Christmas last year and everything went smoothly but this is my first long stay in America so i just want to make sure I'm prepared.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're overthinking this. Just tell the truth and answer any questions you're asked. The only particular thing I can think of is that you should know your friend's address (so you can put it on your landing card) and phone number. Also remember that you'll likely be admitted for 90 days under the visa waiver program, so you should make sure your 12 weeks really isn't any longer. Have a great trip!

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly, you are, as suggested in a comment, overthinking this. It will probably go just as smoothly as your prior visit.

Very, very rarely, I've had immigration officers ask for documents confirming what I've told them.

For example, I have been a US permanent resident since 1978. Usually, I just show my UK passport and US green card when returning home from international travel. One time out of dozens, the officer apparently did not believe I had really lived in the USA for decades, perhaps because I do not have enough of an American accent. He asked some questions about my life in the USA. My answers indicated I live in California and own a house and a car there. He then wanted to see my California driver's license. I did have it, but it was in a money belt under my clothing because I did not expect to need it until the next day.

If you want to be really prepared, put some supporting documents in your carry-on. For your situation, the most useful documents might be an invitation letter from your friend's parents, and acceptance paperwork from your college.

Comment: And a ticket for the return flight.